# How to get data from one Django model to query another model within a template loop?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, database

My Django application has two Models 'Items' & 'Colors' representing database tables 'items' and 'colors'. 
A Django template 'mytemplate.html' renders data gathered from the database with a 'for' loop, printing out a list of items with their properties.

One of the fields of 'items' table is a numeric id that correspond to a text field in 'colors' table. 
Currently I can display all the items with their names and their color numeric id 'cid' (see code below).

But I need to print the color name of an item instead of its 'cid'/'id' within the template loop. What is the most efficient way to achieve this? Do I need an intermediary data structure, alter my database to define a foreign key (items(cid) --> colors(id)), ... ?

I'm not sure that I want to use a foreign key (items(cid) --> colors(id)) because at the time of first insertion of items 'cid' could be undefined (NULL).

**Table 'items'**

```
+------+------+------+
| id   | cid  | name |
+------+------+------+
|  1   |   3  | barZ |
|  2   |   3  | barC |
|  3   |   1  | barE |
|  3   |   2  | barD |
|  4   |   1  | barA |
+------+------+------+
```

**Table 'colors'**

```
+------+---------+
| id   | name    | 
+------+---------+
|  1   |   red   | 
|  2   |   white | 
|  3   |   blue  | 
+------+---------+
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Items(models.Model):
    cid = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'items'

class Colors(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'colors'
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Items
from .models import Colors

def item_list(request):

    items = Items.objects.all().order_by('id')
    colors = Colors.objects.all().order_by('name')

    return render(request,'mytemplate.html',{
        'items': items, 
        'colors': colors  
    })
```

**mytemplate.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Foos</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block page_content %}
<table>
{% for item in items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ items.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ items.cid }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Include your `models` in the question

Comment: @ans2human: Good point, done. Any hints about the actual question?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a foreign key. That foreign key can be set to be [nullable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#null), so it being set as NULL on creation is not a problem.

Afterwards, the color could easily be accessed from the template by doing something like `{{ items.color.name }}`

You can find more information on django model's foreign keys [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).

Comment: carlesgg97: 'id' colum of 'colors' table can't be null in my current implementation so defining 'cid' as a foreign key referencing colors(id) in 'items' table produces an error "ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'mydb.#sql-573_19' (errno: 150). 'cid' can be undefined but colors(id) can't.

Comment: I have made it work with models declared as following: https://pastebin.com/J8Zm970L . How are you declaring your foreign key?

Comment: In raw SQL: ALTER TABLE items ADD FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES colors(id);

Comment: donmelchior: Make sure that the Item.cid column is nullable (it mustn't be declared as NOT NULL nor UNIQUE). For reference, you may take a look at the SQL create table sentences generated by django makemigrations: https://pastebin.com/dhT8mYC3

Answer (score 1):

In this particular use case I can't use foreign key to create a relation between a nullable column (items 'cid') and a non nullable colum (colors 'id').

I created the relation between 'items' table data and 'colors' table data directly within the model using a method 'get_color' which is called later from the template:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Colors(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'colors'

class Items(models.Model):
    cid = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    # New method to grap data from Colors model 
    def get_color(self):
        color_object = Colors.objects.get(id = self.cid)
        color = color_object.name
        return color

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'items'
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Items
from .models import Colors

def item_list(request):

    items = Items.objects.all().order_by('id')
    colors = Colors.objects.all().order_by('name')

    return render(request,'mytemplate.html',{
        'items': items
        # Note: Direct reference to 'colors' table is no longer needed here

    })
```

**mytemplate.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Items</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block page_content %}
<table>
{% for item in items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <!-- get_color method call from model Class instance -->
        <td>{{ item.get_color }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

In many use cases setting a foreign key is a best practice as mentionned. But implementation shown above is usefull, especially if you want to perform additionnal data conversion. Note that you can't directly pass arguments to the method within the template call `'<td>{{ item.get_color }}</td>'`